# Calculate argmax and second argmax of a RasterStack in R

Tags: raster, r, terra

I need to calculate the argmax (index of the maximum) and index of the second maximum of a RasterStack in R. That is, for each pixel of the image, I need to evaluate in which index (layer) is the highest number and which index is the second highest number.

Here an example data:

```
# Example data

library(raster)

r1 <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5); values(r1)= c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.9, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4)
r2 <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5); values(r2)= c(0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.0, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.1)
r3 <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5); values(r3)= c(0.7, 0.4, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5)

# RasterStack
r <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
```

I am able to calculate the argmax of a RasterStack using the `which.max()` function.

```
rArgmax <- which.max(r)
```

How can I get the index of the second maximum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if its the best way, but its easy to find the smallest, and hence with three layers the second-highest will be the one that isn't the highest or the lowest.

```
rArgmax = which.max(r)
rArgmin = which.min(r)
```

each of 1, 2, 3 has to appear in the min, second, and max, so subtract the sum of those two from 6 to get the missing layer number:

```
rArg2 = 6 - (rArgmax+rArgmin)
```

This doesn't work (easily) for more than three layers though.

For deeper stacks use `calc` and `rank`...

This function negates the matrix to reverse the rank order, breaks ties by ranking the first of any tie first, and then returns which element ranks first:

```
> f = function(v){which(rank(-v, ties="first") == 1)}
```

When fed to `calc` with the stack, you get the index of the highest value:

```
> as.matrix(calc(r, f))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    2    3    3    2
[2,]    2    3    2    2    1
[3,]    2    1    1    1    3
[4,]    2    1    3    3    3
[5,]    3    3    3    2    3
```

This looks like your `rArgmax` - good, it should!

Its easily adapted to the second-highest by looking for rank number 2.

```
> f = function(v){which(rank(-v, ties="first") == 2)}
> as.matrix(calc(r, f))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    3    1    1    3
[2,]    1    1    1    3    3
[3,]    1    2    3    2    1
[4,]    3    2    2    1    1
[5,]    1    2    2    1    1
```